# Firestore Query not returning anything

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

I'm working on Angular 7 and Firebase. Where I have two components. Both components are totally different. I want data from one component to the another component.

Let say I want the data from second component to the first component.

So, In first component component.ts file, I have provided the below code.

```
  list: Group[];
  constructor(private groupService : GroupService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
// This line gets the id for the query. and calling the getGroup function from the second component.
    let groupId = this.groupService.getGroupId();
    this.groupService.getGroup(groupId).subscribe(actionArray => {
      this.list = actionArray.map(item => {
        console.log("item :: " + item);
        return {
          id: item.payload.doc.id,
          ...item.payload.doc.data()
        } as Group;
      })
      });
      console.log("List :: " + this.list);
  }
```

In second component, I have provided the function like below where I want the data for particular id document provided in the parameters and the function should return the data from that document.

```
  getGroup(id: string){
    let tempId = id;
    console.log("getGroup() id in GroupService :: " + tempId);

    return this.firestore.collection('groups', ref => ref.where('id','==', tempId)).snapshotChanges();
    // return this.firestore.collection('groups').doc(tempId).get();
  }
```

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: tempId is defined?

Comment: Yes, In getGroup() function the first line.

Comment: And you made sure it's not a number vs string?
Maybe provide the console.log() results.

Comment: It's a string mean id value is string only.